# Getting started with subversion but

Tags: svn

I have never used any type of source control before and I am interested in getting it to subversion. However, I am on shared hosting (DreamHost). How can I get subversion to work? Is there any shared hosting that allows it?

**Update:**
DreamHost has subversion, apparently. Does anyone know if it's the same as the regular subversion?

Comment: Is there something requiring you to learn SVN? If you're just looking to get started with any version control I'd recommend looking at either Git http://github.com or Mercurial http://bitbucket.org .

I personally use Git. I feel it has better branching support, and it's easier to handle merge conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the content of the [dreamhost wiki site](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/index.php/Subversion), dreamhost does offer subversion  (the version control system) hosting, currently at version 1.5.1. The linked site also includes instructions to set up your version control hosting.

I've also used [unfuddle.com](http://unfuddle.com/), offering subversion (and git) hosting for free personal use, very easy to set up.

Answer (score 1):

Beanstalk.com also offers free hosting for personal use. Though if you only need access to the repository on one system, you might prefer to just host it locally. Most SVN clients have an interface for this. Also, if you haven't already read it, the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) is a pretty good reference/getting started guide for Subversion.